# HttpServletRequest to MultipartHttpServletRequest: ClassCastException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow

I want to cast `httpServletRequest` to `multipartHttpServletRequest`. When I try this, a `ClassCastException` occurs.

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest request = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)req;
```

This error occurred only for AJAX call, for form submit it doesn't happen.

I've done all necessary steps as follows:

1. Use `commons-fileupload.jar`
2. Set `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
3. Define `multiparResolver` bean in spring context.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, through Ajax you cannot upload file content, so as request not having any file content spring cannot prepare MultipartHttpServletRequest, which causes `ClassCastException`. Then you have to use technique of using `iframe` in html to upload file while giving `ajax` style upload.

Comment: can pls explain more about how to use iframe in html to upload file with ajax

Comment: But the concept is simple. Whatever appearing on screen as form we capture that form values on submit(by returning false for not submitting that) and prepare hidden iframe on the fly in javascript and preparing the same form and form elements with same values and submits that iframe. There are lot of tutorial on how we can do this using javascript and iframe. google for 'using iframe for file uploads' to understand how we can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from having

```
<form method=<method> action=<url> enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

you have to have

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

in your spring configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

To get the MultipartHttpServletRequest , try this

```
 MultipartHttpServletRequest multiPartRequest = new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(req);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am trying  this but java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multipart request not initialized exception occurred.

Comment: Please read the link of MultipartHttpServletRequest  [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) and see what you're missing .